# HTML mp4 video element not showing on UC mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, mp4, uc-browser

Does UC Browser support mp4 videos? I have a video element inside my Html code which is not rendered correctly on UC mobile browser.

Below the code:

````
<video :poster="poster" muted autoplay playsinline loop autobuffer style="width:100%;" onended="var v=this;setTimeout(function(){v.play()},300)">
      <source :src="src" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
```
````

Comment: Try without those strange `:` colon marks. Example `<source src="myfile.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>`.

Comment: I cannot avoid the colon marks as these are part of the Vue framework I am using.